# Application Destination needs to be in Projects or Application - ArgoCD?

Tags: devops, argocd, gitops, argocd-notification

I am confused on the "application destination" as I am getting different errors when I am adding the destination within the Application config vs Projects Config.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the `my-project` project does not permit your Application's destination (the local cluster, in the `argocd` namespace).

Make sure your project allows that server and namespace.

Comment: Actually adding the below fixed the issue:



  'clusterResourceWhitelist:
  - group: '*'
    kind: '*' '

Comment: Interesting. That's a really surprising error message for that config issue.

Comment: Looks like allowing (basically whitelisting) everything "*" fixed the issue my allowing the projects to deploy in the applications. I will keep you posted if I hit snag with more modifications on its way. Appreciate the reply here Crenshaw.